# jquery show next div, hide current span?

Tags: jquery, html

When I click a link I want the next DIV to show, but the current SPAN to hide. I can get the next div showing, but I'm strugging with hiding the current span. Here's my code:

jquery:

```
$(".post").hide();
$(".hide,.show").show();

$('.show').click(function() {
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
    <Hide current span here, how?>
    return false;
    });
```

html:

```
<span class=lowrated>Low-rated post hidden. <a href="#" class="show">Show</a></span>

<div class="post">post goes here</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).next('div')` should not work either, since there's no sibling `div`.

```
$('.show').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('span').hide().next('div').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: yeah its closing the span but not opening the div with that :s

Comment: Hmm, it works for me. You're still using `$(".post").hide()`, right? [Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4sLcpkr6/).

Answer (score 0):

the `span` is the `parent` of the `.show` class `a` element.

```
$(this).parent().slideToggle(); //or .hide() or .css("display","none")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following:

```
$(this).parent().hide();
```

or

```
$(this).closest('span').hide();
```

Note that you'll also need to use either .`parent()` or `.closest('span')` with the code you have to make the div show since the link has no next element:

```js
$(".post").hide();
$(".hide,.show").show();

$('.show').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().next('div').slideToggle();
  $(this).parent().hide();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class=lowrated>Low-rated post hidden. <a href="#" class="show">Show</a></span>

<div class="post">post goes here</div>
```